# How do I set the `startAt` date when using Angular Material Calendar?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using material2 v2.0.0-beta.10 as well as Angular v4 and having issues when using `md-calendar` component. My problem is that I'm unable to set the `startAt` date to anything.

I set start date to yesterday as follows:

```
  this.startAt = new Date();
  this.startAt = this.startAt.setDate(this.startDate - 1);
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wRAa5eyW5cTCdKEBIcXI?p=preview) is a Plunkr of attempting to set the `startAt` date to yesterday.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just update everything to v4? Try to keep up in the end it will limit you alot.

Comment: @Swoox I am using Angular v4 and material 2 v2.0.0-beta.10. Updated the question to reflect this fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The start date accepts the following format:

```
startDate = new Date(1990, 0, 1);
```

Citing from the docs:

> The month or year that the calendar opens to is determined by first
> checking if any date is currently selected, if so it will open to the
> month or year containing that date. Otherwise it will open to the
> month or year containing today's date. This behavior can be overridden
> by using the startAt property of md-datepicker. In this case the
> calendar will open to the month or year containing the startAt date.

So if you wish, say, to set the starting date to the next month, the following code should work:

```
let today = new Date();
let month = today.getMonth() + 1; //next month
let year = today.getUTCFullYear();
let day = today.getDay();

this.startAt = new Date(year, month, day);
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukqeff?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.ts)**

Comment: I must have glanced over that detail. Using this code, it appears the selected date is changed, but the day isn't highlighted in blue. Guess there's a bug. Thank you.

Comment: I think it works the way that the selected day is always system "today" but it opens on the "start" day's page

Comment: Thank you for the update. I came up with [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/cEcISQ9USbNm6SuYEkn9?p=preview), which fixes the issue of selecting new dates wasn't highlighting properly.